# Compiling Java program with multiple classes on Linux

Tags: java, compiler-construction

So far I have been able to compile my Java programs in Linux using javac command in Terminal, but soon I'll need to compile a program that has two or three classes in it along with main and I'm not sure how this will work.

Can I still use javac command for this?

Comment: For larger projects you should think of automating the build process. E.g. using a build tool like Maven, Gradle or Ivy.

Comment: I would use a build system like `maven` This will allows you do build complex and download libraries as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you would use a build system such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org), [ANT](http://ant.apache.org), etc

If you are just compiling classes which are in the current working directory, and you have not used packages, you can quite happily use

```
$ javac *.java
```

If you have used some packages (and have put the files in their correct package directories) you can use

```
$ javac $(find . -name \*.java)
```

When you get to a large number of files, you will need to list them in a file and reference that via a `@` argument, eg

```
$ find . -name \*.java > ./java-files.txt
$ javac @./java-files.txt
```

But ultimately a build tool will make life a lot easier.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just do `javac *.java` (if all your classes are in the default package).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  From the oracle javac page

> There are two ways to pass source code file names to javac:
>
> For a small number of source files, simply list the file names on the command line.
>
> For a large number of source files, list the file names in a file, separated by blanks or line breaks. Then use the list file name on the javac command line, preceded by an @ character.

[See the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html)